# Skype doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my Dell PC but last time Skype didnt work under Ubuntu 14.04  LTS. Do I have to update Ubuntu to 14.04.1 or update Skype?

Answer (score 0):

Skype is a 32-bit package. When trying to install it via the console, there are confusing messages about needed dependencies which are seemingly already met on a 64-bit system. The problem is that the 32-bit libraries need to be installed for Skype to work.

First, remove the broken Skype package:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

Then, install the necessary 32-bit libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-gui:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libxss1:i386 libxv:i386
```

Finally, install Skype:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
```

---

#### Alternate (much easier) method

Simply add the Partner repositories.

1. Open the Software Center
2. Edit -> Software Sources
3. "Other Software" tab
4. Check the box that says "Canonical Partners" in bold
5. Upon closing, the software sources will be refreshed
6. Then, search for Skype and install!

Comment: Or just install it from the [Canonical Partner repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html#canonical-partner) and be saved such concerns. ;)

Comment: Honestly, I had forgot all about the partner repositories! I'll add that to the answer as well.